# What effect will the Saudi modernization initiative have on foreign workers?

Tags: saudi-arabia

One of the components of [MBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad_bin_Salman)'s modernization initiative was adding/raising taxes for family members of foreign citizens. They are also going to ban foreign nationals from engaging in some specific professions.

Would the low wage workers (e.g. construction laborers, airport cleaners, home servants, etc) from Nepal, Pakistan, India, Bangladesh, and Philippines be able to continue their jobs, or, would they have to go back to their respective countries?

Comment: I don't see how he can raise taxes on foreign citizens if he's also repatriating them.